# JUnit test throw java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I've transformed my eclipse Dynamic Web Project in Maven web-application and the application work when i deploy it on my tomcat server but i can't find how to run my JUnit test.

Previously i was running them by clicking on them and "run as Junit Test" but when i do it Eclipse throw this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiNameException
```

Can someone explain me why ? Or how to do it properly?

Thx

Comment: did u try Maven -> Update project

Comment: I've just tried to update as you said but it doesn't change anything ...

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency to JUnit in your pom.xml.